# Cannot add http headers to gin client (Resolver context)

Tags: go, httpclient, gqlgen

I want to add headers to the request for testing. Further, I want to move any headers I want to access in resolvers into context.

PR [#861](https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen/pull/861) featured a way to add HTTP headers across a whole client or per request. This does not work for me. I tried adding a header to the client like this:

```
c = client.New(srv, client.AddHeader("Header", "HeaderValue"))
```

There is no error or anything, the header just isn't added. I also tried adding the header in a request, as a parameter to `c.MustPost` and got the same result.

Maybe a middleware can help

```
var srv = handler.NewDefaultServer(generated.NewExecutableSchema(NewRootResolvers()))
// Maybe a middleware to wrap around srv
var c = client.New(srv)
```

**versions**

- gqlgen version - latest
- go version - latest

Exactly these requirements: https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen/issues/1330

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution to this.
We can add context to the request, using options...

```
srv := handler.NewDefaultServer(generated.NewExecutableSchema(generated.Config{Resolvers: &resolvers}))
c := client.New(srv, func(bd *client.Request){
    bd.HTTP = bd.HTTP.WithContext(context.WithValue(bd.HTTP.Context(), "key", "Value"))
})
```

With this we can get  the headers as resolver context.